# jQuery Adding Class to Dynamic Menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, business-catalyst

I am trying to add a class to a dynamically generated menu using jQuery. I am building the site on Business Catalyst so I do not have access to the server side code. I tried using the **.addClass()** method to add a class to my ul item. I am doing this because I am using Twitter Bootstrap and Business Catalyst generates ul menus with a unique id and not a class. **The code I tried does not appear to add a class to the ul element in my menu.** Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
    <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          {module_menu,14623}
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav_14623").addClass("nav");
});
</script>
```

Website URL:
http://jshub.designangler.com/

Comment: please describe what is not working.

Comment: When I open the developer console I am seeing an error saying $ is not defined, but also, if you type this in the console, $("#nav_14623").addClass("nav");, it adds the class, so as Pat mentioned, whats happening?

Comment: "$ is not defined" means that jQuery hasn't been loaded. Are the script references in the page below the snippet of javascript you posted?

Comment: Is jQuery properly installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script code is being added before the jquery code is included you have to put your script code after it

Currenttly looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul#nav_14623").addClass("nav");
    });
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js" /></script>
```

Needs to be

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js" /></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul#nav_14623").addClass("nav");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Derp >_<

Thanks. I am such a dummy. =)

Answer (score 0):

Run this to test whether your have jQuery first:

```
<script>
$(function(){

alert('jQuery ok!')
})

</script>
```

If you get an alert, then jQuery is there if not, then no jQuery is installed or not properly set.